# excel: advanced filter with protected sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have this sheet where I use Advanced Filter to search for informations inside another sheet in my workbook.

In addition, I want to protect sheet because I have some formulas on cells that people shouldn't be able to change but I also have cells that the user should come with some information then I've already unlocked these cells as you can see below:

[image]

The problem is when I try to run my Advanced Filter when I click my "Filter" button. I get an error message that says:

> Advanced Filter can't run in Protected Sheet.

So I associated this code to my "Filter" button:

```
Private Sub Filtrar_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wks.Unprotect "Password"
    Call LimparAntes
    wks.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next

End Sub
```

The **LimparAntes** sub is the routine that calls Advanced Filter, but I still get the same mistake so I'm in doubt. The code is below:

```
Sub LimparAntes()
'
' LimparAntes Macro
'

'
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Sheets("AUX").Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("AUX").Range("A1:K" & Lastrow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("CONSULTA").Range("D34:I35"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("CONSULTA").Range("B40:K40"), Unique:= _
        False
    Sheets("CONSULTA").Range("F37").Select

End Sub
```

Is that the correct way to do that? I've made a lot of research but I couldn't find anyone with the same problem with Advanced Filter as I so I don't even know if it's possible to achieve what I want.

Comment: Unlocked cells are, well, *unlocked* when the sheet is protected. If you want the user to NOT be able to tamper with the formulas, you need these cells locked. What's `LimparAntes` doing?

Comment: @Mat'sMug sorry, I've already corrected that. I have cells that need to be unlocked for the user can change the value there. `LimparAntes` is the name of the sub that calls my advanced filter to search my criteria. I also edited the question with its code.

Comment: Is the *workbook* protected as well?

Comment: If the answer to @Mat's question about the _workbook_ is no, the problem could be that you protect and unprotect one sheet at the time, but the `LimparAntes` needs 2 sheets to complete the work: `Sheets("AUX")` and `Sheets("CONSULTA")`, and one of them will always be protected

Comment: Yes, the sheets was already protected before I started to test my code. I try just to lock one sheet but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this all of the code?

Just from looking at the code without executing it, the first steps should be to unlock/unprotect ALL sheets by doing:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wks.Unprotect "Password"
Next
```

Then upon completion, you should run LimparAntes().  That will then copy/filter the data you need.  And then finally you should lock the sheets.

```
Private Sub Filtrar_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wks.Unprotect "Password"    'Unprotect all sheets first
Next

Call LimparAntes     'Call filter sub

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wks.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True     'Re-Protect all sheets
Next

End Sub
```

Try this and see if it removes the error.  If not, I have read that setting the autofilter property to True prior to locking the sheet may be beneficial.

Comment: Sorry for taking a long time to check it, but it worked! Thank you that much, I didn't notice that I should repeat the complete code again, that was my doubt.